# Regular expressions to get all digits and few special characters in java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions and wanting allow a message with following characters to be approved. A message with any number of digits, and number of special characters like `<` `>` `.` `*` `;` `"` `,` `#` `%` `&` `)` `(` `=` `+` `-` `!` `space` `new_line`

Rest of the characters like `@` `~` `{` `[` `alphabetical letters` etc.. should not be approved.

```
java.util.regex.Pattern my_pattern = null;
my_pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*(0-9|<|>|.|*|;|\"|,|#|%|&|\\(|\\)|=|\+|-|!|\s|\n).*");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `character class`:

```
Pattern.compile("^[0-9<>.*;\",#%&()=+!\\s-]+$");
```

There is no need to escape these special characters inside character class and it is more efficient that alternation using multiple pipes. Also note that I removed `\n` since `\s` already matches newlines.

Comment: I'm not sure about Java regex character classes, but shouldn't the "-" character be the first character inside the character class if we need to match it literally?

Comment: @diveshpremdeep: `-` can be 1st or last in character class to avoid escaping.